# Card display vue js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm new to vue.js and I'm currently practicing it with vuetify. I'm trying to make this layout for hours but I'm still stuck. Can anyone help me by explaining how to approach this problem please?

I have an array of objects which contains a description and an image. I would like to display them like in the picture below.[image]

The first card, i'll display a description, the second one, an image. When changing row, for example the second row, I'll keep an image just like the fourth card. The eighth and ninth will be text and continue alternating from there.

```js
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <v-container grid-list-lg>
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <v-layout row>
        <v-flex lg3 v-for="(item, index) in arr" :key="item.id" class="space-bottom">
          <v-card class="mx-auto" max-width="344" outlined>
            <v-list-item three-line>
              <v-list-item-content v-if="index % 2 === 0" height="400px">
                <v-list-item-subtitle>{{item.description}}</v-list-item-subtitle>

                <v-list-item-subtitle class="subtitle-style">
                  <span>
                    <a href="#">Read more</a>
                  </span>
                </v-list-item-subtitle>
              </v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item>

            <v-hover>
              <template v-slot:default="{ hover }">
                <v-list-item-content v-if="index % 2 !== 0">
                  <img :src="item.imageUrl" />

                  <v-fade-transition>
                    <v-overlay v-if="hover" absolute color="#036358">
                      <v-btn>See more info</v-btn>
                    </v-overlay>
                  </v-fade-transition>
                </v-list-item-content>
              </template>
            </v-hover>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {},
  data() {
    return {
      arr: [
        {
          description: "description 1",
          imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/100"
        },
        {
          description: "description 2",
          imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/100"
        },
        {
          description: "description 3",
          imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/100"
        },
        {
          description: "description 4",
          imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/100"
        },
        {
          description: "description 1",
          imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/100"
        },
        {
          description: "description 1",
          imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/100"
        },
        {
          description: "description 1",
          imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/100"
        },
        {
          description: "description 2",
          imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/100"
        },
        {
          description: "description 3",
          imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/100"
        },
        {
          description: "description 4",
          imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/100"
        },
        {
          description: "description 1",
          imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/100"
        },
        {
          description: "description 1",
          imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/100"
        }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Currently, it is like this:
[image]

Comment: I've tried mostly the same thing over and over since I cannot find any other way to do it, that's why I decided to post here to find other perspectives.

What I tried is:
Have two 
<v-flex v-for="(item, index) in items">
  <v-list-item-content v-if="index % 2 === 0"></v-list-item-content>
  <v-list-item-content v-if="index % 2 !== 0"></v-list-item-content>
</v-flex>

It works but on the 5th card, it changes to text which is normal the way I did it.

Sorry for not having posted what I've tried already and thank you for responding.

Comment: Does the contents of your cards change on different responsiveness intervals?

Comment: I'm currently editing the example to show you. I will post it in a minute. I'm not making it responsive for now, I just started learning Vue two days ago :p

Comment: I just edited the post to insert the code. Please let me know if you need any more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>This should do it:</strike>

```
methods: {
  getCardType(index) {
    return (this.rowLength * 2 + index) % (this.rowLength * 2) >= this.rowLength
      ? index % 2 ? 'text' : 'img'
      : index % 2 ? 'img' : 'text'
  }
}
```

Where `rowLength` is `4`:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    rowLength: 4
  }),
  methods: {
    getCardType(index) {
      return (this.rowLength * 2 + index) % (this.rowLength * 2) >= this.rowLength
        ? index % 2 ? 'text' : 'img'
        : index % 2 ? 'img' : 'text'
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="n in 100" class="card" :style="{flex: `1 0 ${100/rowLength}%`}">{{getCardType(n - 1)}}</div>
</div>
```

It can probably be simplified and/or adjusted for a different number of items/row.

Here's a version which keeps the "chekers" pattern on both odd and even number of columns:

```
getCardType(index) {
  return this.rowLength % 2 ||
  (this.rowLength * 2 + index) % (this.rowLength * 2) >= this.rowLength
  ? index % 2 ? 'text' : 'img'
  : index % 2 ? 'img' : 'text'
}
```

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    rowLength: 4
  }),
  methods: {
    getCardType(index) {
      return this.rowLength % 2 ||
      (this.rowLength * 2 + index) % (this.rowLength * 2) >= this.rowLength
      ? index % 2 ? 'text' : 'img'
      : index % 2 ? 'img' : 'text'
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.columns {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.card {
  padding: 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.img {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>Columns: <input type="number" v-model="rowLength"></div>
  <div class="columns">
    <div v-for="n in 100" class="card"
         :style="{flex: `1 0 ${100/rowLength}%`}"
         :class="[getCardType(n - 1)]"
         >{{getCardType(n - 1)}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

which, in English, would be: return `img` or `text` based on `index` parity but reverse the condition on even rows if the number of items per row is even.

Comment: I did not understand all that you did, but it works. Thank you very much, I'll stop banging my head and try to understand your code now :D

Comment: The "longer" condition there is: (in English): *Are we on the second half of modulus of twice the row size*? Which is basically: *Are we on an even row*? We only care for this when the `rowSize` is even, because in that case we want to flip the condition on even rows. Condition being `index % 2`. When `rowSize` is  odd, the only condition for checkers pattern is `index % 2`. Makes sense?